# How to register types in class libraries with vnext?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

is there any way to register types (i.e. repositories) for a mvc 6 (vnext) application within the dnx class libraries? I don't want to call AddTransient<,>() within the startup class hundreds of times. For a n-tier application this seems not to be the best approach.

Comment: What do you mean by *"within the dnx class libraries"*?

Comment: I like to move the mapping of the interface types with the object types into my class libraries for having a plugin enviroment.

Answer (score 2):

Basic IoC vNext use doesn't have scanning abilities/batch registration.

In your case you should use some of "big" ioc containers like Ninject, Unity, StructrureMap...

Comment: Well, i tried this too, but i failed to load the dependencies from the ILibraryManager into the ContainerBuilder because the Container has to be build before the LibraryManager is initialized,

Answer (score 2):

You class libraries you can follow the same approach the rest of the framework uses which uses extension methods on `IServiceCollection`.  eg. `AddMvc`, `AddEntityFramework`, etc.

For "automatic" registration, nothing exists out of the box, but I've built a library that gives you a `[ServiceDescriptor]` attribute, that you can use to bind your interfaces to your classes (or just apply to a class).

https://github.com/Blacklite/DependencyInjection/tree/master/src/Blacklite.Framework.DependencyInjection

The `AddAssembly(...)` extension method just assembly surfs to find all your `[ServiceDescriptor]` attributes and adds them to the services collection.

Then to use it you just need to do one of the following:

1. Add the extension method like above, and have the extenstion method simply call `services.AddAssembly(typeof(ExtensionClassInAssembly))`

   I find this the simplist, also it allows you to remove the AddAssembly method and replace it with something else without having to change your main startup class.
2. Add a call to `services.AddAssembly(typeof(TypeInAssembly))` to your Startup.cs

Comment: Nice idea, but it looks a little bit hacky. :D I would like to reuse the build in services. I have provided a not working example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674104/self-registering-libraries-with-autofac-4-and-vnext