# Autofac 4 and vNext beta-7 and Signal-Server 3.0 beta-7

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac, dnx

i'am play with ASP.NET vnext and SignalR. As IoC i want to use Autofac.

For this i found a perfect example: 
[Self-Registering Libraries with Autofac 4 and vNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674104/self-registering-libraries-with-autofac-4-and-vnext) from @endeffects

There is exactly described what i want. But it dosen't work: 
I mean my Objects will be not injected. And my PersistentConnection (no Hub) object are not created. But i did not see any errors or exceptions.

When i remove the requested interface from my PersistentConnection constructor, the connection will be established and all is fine. But i haven't my requested object instance how implement the desired interface.

Is there any breaking changes since end of July in Autofac and DNX?

I'am using:  DNX beta-7

- "Autofac": "4.0.0-beta8-135",
- "Autofac.Dnx": "4.0.0-alpha4-79"
- "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-beta7"

Comment: @mason sorry i have set a wrong link to Self-Registering Libraries with Autofac 4 and vNext (now it is fixed). There you can find the complete code, what i'am also used.

Answer (score 0):

oh damn,

as described in my question post i'am using this code from here: [Self-Registering Libraries with Autofac 4 and vNext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674104/self-registering-libraries-with-autofac-4-and-vnext)

In the deep of my code, i found one type how has no paramterless constructor and the required type are not registered in IoC. I fix that to change to an parameterless constructor. Now it works

But my major problem is, that i did not get any exceptions or some other hint about that issue. It will be swallowed anywhere between SignalR or Autofac.