# How to make the connection string available in a N-Tier ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 App with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, n-tier-architecture, autofac-module

I wired the layer together via autofac *modules*. Big thanks to [endeffects](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4713868/endeffects). [Here is the HowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674104/self-registering-libraries-with-autofac-4-and-vnext). Now I'm trying to make the connection string available in the DAL layer. I tried to register the:

```
Configuration (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration)
```

From the *Startup* class but without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following line in my ConfigureServices method in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton(serviceType => Configuration);
services.AddInstance<Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration>(Configuration);

builder.Populate(services);
var container = builder.Build();
var serviceProvider = container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
return serviceProvider;
```

Then in my DAL, I access that via constructor injections like:

```
public MyDataContext(IConfiguration configurations)
```

I can then access that item and pull my connection info like:

```
configurations["Data:MyConnection:ConnectionString"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Armstrong but I'm using autofac and not the DI from ASP.NET Core. But I'm trying basically the same with autoface...

Comment: Edited my answer with the remaining code to populate your services into your autofac builder, and then return the appropriate service provider.

Comment: `AddInstance` has been renamed to `AddSingleton` https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/119

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of my DAL needing to know anything about the name of the connection string, I don't think that is part of it's repsonsibility.  I prefer creating my own interface:

So for instance I would create something like:

```
public interface IConnectionSettings
{
  public ConnectionStringSettings DataWarehouse { get; }
  public ConnectionStringSettings Audit { get; }
  public ConnectionStringSettings Logging { get; }
  public ConnectionStringSettings Security { get; }
}
```

Then when I'm using Entity Framework with DI

```
public class SecurityContext : DbContext
{
  public SecurityContext(IConnectionSettings settings)
    : base (settings.Name)
  {
  }
}
```

Or ADO.Net for some weird reason:

```
public class LoggingDataAccess
{
  private readonly string _connectionString;

  public LoggingDataAccess(IConnectionSettings settings)
  {
    _connectionString = settings.Logging.ConnectionString;
  }

  public void SomeRawAdo()
  {
    using (var con = new Connection(_connnectionstring))
    {
    }
  }
}
```

In my DI:

```
public static class IocCOnfig
{
  public static void Start()
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(r => new ConnectionSettings
    {
      DataWarehouse = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataWarehouse"],
      // etc
    });
  }

  private class ConnectionSettings : IConnectionSettings
  {
    // implement interface...
  }
}
```